# Facebook login button click doing nothing

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I successfully set up the Facebook SDK 4.4.1 in my Eclipse.

I wrote some simple code in my `MainActivity` and XML.

Here is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.facebookintegration.MainActivity" >

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/login_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here I only declare the Facebook button.

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
LoginButton lb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lb=(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Facebook Login Activity","Performed Successfully");
    super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

When I press the login button of Facebook, it shows the spinner and after some time it goes back to the `MainActivity`.

Is my app is performing the login or not? If not, what code do I need to add?

Also, how would I get the `AccessToken` for getting the user Detail?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dr37k2ihe3rlc9o/Screenshot_2015-08-10-19-36-08.png?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zs8g4p88iwv9v5/Screenshot_2015-08-10-19-36-12.png?dl=0

Comment: please refer above two image that's what happening with my app

Comment: If these are related to your question, you should add them to the question by editing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are missing is a callback.

Try this:
Declare your callback manager

```
public static CallbackManager callbackmanager;
```

Now create it in `onCreate()` using this

```
callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

Don't forget to set permissions to your login button

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email", "user_friends");
```

And now register the callback

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackmanager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged in successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i(TAG, "Facebook login successful.");

                // you can make a new graph request for user info here
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging in canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i(TAG, "Facebook login canceled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred while logging in. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i(TAG, "Facebook login error.");
            }
        });
```

And you're also gonna need to call the callback manager's onActivityResult()

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackmanager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

For more info about permorfing graph requests [Facebook SDK Graph - Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph)

Comment: Thanku @cvetanov so much actually i had tried the code that you provide before but i am just lacking a single line callbackmanager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  after a  long search you made my day :)